# can't able to increase column value from its current existing value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i have designed a webpage in mobile using Jquery mobile. I have a table and few images. Intially i am populating random values to the columns in that table. On clicking a image, particular column value in table should get increased(here i have taken column 4). Here on clicking image,particular column value gets increased.

But the problem is when i clicked the image,the column value starts increasing from 0. What i need is, it has to be increased from existing column value.

```
var currentAdjustment = null;
var val = 0;
var beginAdjust = function(amount) {
                currentAdjustment = amount;
                setTimeout(checkAdjust, 100);
                };

                var checkAdjust = function() {
                    if (currentAdjustment !== null) {
                        makeAdjustment(currentAdjustment);
                        setTimeout(checkAdjust, 200);
                    }
                };

                var makeAdjustment = function(amt) {
                    val += amt;
                    $('#TableRowID td:nth-child(4)').text(val);
                };

                $('.upperArrow').bind('touchstart', function(){
                                  var CurrentColumnVal =  $("#TableRowID td:nth-child(4)").text();
                                  beginAdjust(1);
                                  }).bind('touchend', function(){
                                          currentAdjustment = null;
                                          });
```

i can get existing column value(CurrentColumnVal) in string format & tried to increase from there, which is not working.

Comment: can you create fiddle for your problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var thisIsAString = "2";
thisIsAString = thisIsAString + 1; // equals "21" (String concatenation)

var stringCastToNumber = Number("2");   // parseInt("2") would do as well
stringCastToNumber = stringCastToNumber + 1;  // equals 3
```

Your `CurrentColumnVal` points to a string. Cast it to a number.

Answer (score 2):

Please Parse incremented value from string into `parseInt(val)`.